# Сравнить два массива и удалить дубликаты из обоих

Tags: javascript

Есть объект:

```
{
  "rating_summary": {
    "bad": [
      "time_of_day",
      "waiting_time"
    ],
    "good": [
      "food",
      "waiting_time",
      "time_of_day",
      "airport_change"
    ]
  }
}
```

Как видно, в массивах с ключами `bad` и `good` есть дубли. Мне нужно удалить дубли из обоих массивов. То есть, по итогу работы алгоритма должно получиться два массива:

```
"bad": [],
"good": [
    "food",
    "airport_change"
]
```

Как это сделать? Пытался нагуглить, но везде предлагают лишь алгоритмы, которые возвращают один массив без дублей или возвращают только дубли из двух массивов. А `reduce()` позволяет пройтись только в пределах одного массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. переводим оба массива в объект. Так что имена полей - это значения массивов bad и good, а значения полей: 1 - если значение присутствует только в массиве bad, 2 - только в good и 3 - в обоих
2. пробегаем по всем полям объекта. Если значение поля равно 1, то помещаем его в выходной массив bad, если значение поля равно 2, то помещаем его в выходной массив good.

```js
const rating_summary = JSON.parse(`{
    "bad": [
        "time_of_day",
        "waiting_time"
    ],
    "good": [
        "food",
        "waiting_time",
        "time_of_day",
        "airport_change"
    ]
}`);

const sum = {};
for(let i=0; i<rating_summary.bad.length; i+=1){
    sum[rating_summary.bad[i]] = 1;
}

for(let i=0; i<rating_summary.good.length; i+=1){
    sum[rating_summary.good[i]] = sum[rating_summary.good[i]] === undefined ? 2 : 3;
}

const bad = [];
const good = [];

for(let k in sum){
    if(sum[k] == 1){
        bad.push(k);
    }else if(sum[k] == 2){
        good.push(k);
    }
}

console.log(bad);
console.log(good);
```

Comment: Интересное решение, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

```js
var obj = {
  "rating_summary": {
    "bad": [
      "time_of_day",
      "waiting_time"
    ],
    "good": [
      "food",
      "waiting_time",
      "time_of_day",
      "airport_change"
    ]
  }
};

function arrayToKeys(a) {
  var res = Object.create(null);

  for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) {
    res[a[q]] = true;
  }
  
  return res;
}

var bad = arrayToKeys(obj.rating_summary.bad);
var good = arrayToKeys(obj.rating_summary.good);

obj.rating_summary.bad = obj.rating_summary.bad.filter(function (x) {
  return !good[x];
});

obj.rating_summary.good = obj.rating_summary.good.filter(function (x) {
  return !bad[x];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, "  "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Если скорость не важна, то можно предложить ещё такое простое короткое решение:

```js
let obj = {
    rating_summary: {
        bad: [
            'time_of_day',
            'waiting_time'
        ],
        good: [
            'food',
            'waiting_time',
            'time_of_day',
            'airport_change'
        ]
    }
};

let common = obj.rating_summary.bad.filter(x => obj.rating_summary.good.includes(x));
let bad = obj.rating_summary.bad.filter(x => !common.includes(x));
let good = obj.rating_summary.good.filter(x => !common.includes(x));

console.log(bad);
console.log(good);
```